# Cannot find symbol when referring to an inner class in another file

Tags: java

So I have this project I am working on and I need to create my own ArrayList class for it. I have all my methods defined, but when I compile I keep getting a "cannot find symbol" error for three of my methods. I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface FBList {

    public int size();

public void insert(int i, Person person);

public Person remove(int i);

public Person lookUp(int i);

/**
*A class that defines a person
**/
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private long phoneNum;

    public Person(String personID, long phoneNum){
        id = personID;
        phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an inner class in there. I am trying to use that class in my other file which implements this interface. Currently, the three methods in my other file giving me the issue are as follows:

```
/**
    * A method to expand the size of the array if the array is too small
    * @param i  One minus the place in the list where the component will be inserted
    * @param Person The person to be put in the list
    **/
    protected void expandInsert(int i, Person person){
        Person[] temp = new Person[arrayList.length * 2];
        for(int index = 0; index < temp.length; index++){
            if( i != index){
                if(i > 0)
                    temp[index] = arrayList[index];
                if(i == 0)
                    temp[index + 1] = arrayList[index];
            }
            else{
                temp[i] = person;
                i = 0;
                index--;
            }
        }
        arrayList = temp;
    }

/**
    * Inserts a new component at the end of a list by creating a new list longer that then last
    * @param i The place in the list where the component will be inserted
    * @param Person The person to be added to the list
    **/

protected void insertAtEnd(int i, Person person){
    Person[] temp = new Person[arrayList.length + 5];
    for(int index = 0; index < temp.length; index++){
        if(index != i){
            temp[index] = arrayList[index];
        }
        else{
            temp[index] = person;
        }
    }
    arrayList = temp;
}

/**
* Shrinks the array by one by removing one component from the array
* @param i The index to be removed
**/

protected void shrink(int i){
    Person[] temp = new Person[arrayList.length - 1];
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayList.length ; index++ ) {
        if (index < i) {
            temp[index] = arrayList[index];
        }
        else if (index == i){
            removedPerson = arrayList[index];
            temp[index] = arrayList[index + 1];
        }
        else{
            temp[index - 1] = arrayList[index];
        }
    }
}
```

All of these files are in the same folder, so there shouldn't be an issue there. I am using terminal to compile by typing "javac FBArrayList.java". My compiler output looks like this:

```
 FBArrayList.java:106: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method expandInsert(int,FBList.Person)
location: class FBList.Person[]
            arrayList.expandInsert(i, person);
                     ^
FBArrayList.java:108: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method insertAtEnd(int,FBList.Person)
location: class FBList.Person[]
            arrayList.insertAtEnd(i, person);
                     ^
FBArrayList.java:118: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method shrink(int)
location: class FBList.Person[]
        arrayList.shrink(i);
                 ^
3 errors
```

Comment: Why is `Person` an inner class? Why should a `Person` only be relevant within the context of an `FBList`?

Comment: When I did that, I was setting up my interface and I needed references to Person for my methods.

Comment: Why can't you refer to an outside `Person` class? Interfaces shouldn't be restricted to the scope of one class, surely they can refer to other classes as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `Person` is an inner class, its name needs to be *qualified* with the name of the outer class:

```
protected void expandInsert(int i, FBList.Person person){
    FBList.Person[] temp = new FBList.Person[arrayList.length * 2];
    ...
    // and so on...
}
```

**EDIT:** Removed a suggestion to make class `static` because the class is nested inside an *interface*. The suggestion would have been required for classes nested inside classes; for interfaces, `static` is optional.

Comment: So I tried this, but my compiler output is still like this: `FBArrayList.java:56: package FBlist does not exist
 protected void insertAtEnd(int i, FBlist.Person person){
                                         ^
FBArrayList.java:106: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method expandInsert(int,FBList.Person)
location: class FBList.Person[]
   arrayList.expandInsert(i, person);
            ^
FBArrayList.java:108: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method insertAtEnd(int,FBList.Person)
location: class FBList.Person[]
   arrayList.insertAtEnd(i, person);
            ^
` Sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: @Dave I think you misspelled `FBList` (the third `L` should be upper case).

Comment: Thanks, I did corrected that, but for some reason I am still getting the same output as above. :/

Comment: @Dave I tried this on ideone, [and your code compiled correctly](http://ideone.com/2HXtcK). When you put your classes in different files, make sure that you declare them in the same package (i.e. the `package` directive, if any, is the same in all files from your related package, and that the path to the files follows the structure of the name of the package.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I was calling methods on the array itself instead of using `this.`. It now compiles fine. Thank you!